# AVX Intrinsic Clarification, 4x4 Matrix Multiplication Oddities

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, avx

On paper I drew out the long form of this algorithm, and on paper it should work fine. Am I running into a subtlety with register casting (256/128/256), or did I actually mess up the algorithm structure somewhere?

For convenience, I've put the vanilla code and the AVX code up on the Godbolt viewer so you can see the generated assembly at will.

Standard code 
https://godbolt.org/g/v47RKH

My AVX Attempt 1:
https://godbolt.org/g/oH1DpO

My AVX Attempt 2:
https://godbolt.org/g/QFtdKr (Shaved 5 cycles and reduced casting needs, easier to read)

The SSE code oddly enough is using scalar operations, which boggles my mind since that can definitely be accelerated with horizontal broadcasts, muls, and adds. What I'm trying to do is take that concept up one level.

RHS never needs to be changed, but essentially if LHS is {a, b, ..., p},
and LHS is {1, 2, ..., 16}, then we just need 2 registers to hold the 2 halves of RHS and then 2 registers to hold a given row of LHS in the forms {a, a, a, a, b, b, b, b} and {c, c, c, c, d, d, d, d}. This is achieved via 2 broadcasts and a 256/128/256 cast.

We get the intermediate results of

> {a*1, a*2, a*3, a*4, b*5, b*6, b*7, b*8} => row[0]

and

> {c*9, c*10, c*11, c*12, d*13, d*14, d*15, d*16} => row[1]

And this is unrolled once w.r.t LHS so we generate

> {e*1, ... f*8}, {g*9, ... h*16} => row[2], row[3]

Next add r0,r1 and r2,r3 together (keeping r0 and r2 as the current intermediates)

Finally, extract the high half of row[0] to the low half of resHalf, insert the low half of row[2] into the high half of resHalf, insert the high half of row[2] into the high half of row[0], and then add row[0] to resHalf.

By all rights, that should leave us with resHalf[0] equaling the following at the end of iteration i = 0

> {a*1 + b*2 + c*3 + d*4, a*5 + b*6 + c*7 + d*8,
>
> a*9 + b*10 + c*11 + d*12, a*13 + b*14 + c*15 + d*16,
>
> e*1 + ... + h*4, e*5 + ... + h*8,
>
> e*9 + ... + h*12, e*13 + ... + h*16}

What my algorithm is producing, however, is the following:

> 2x {a*1 + c*3, a*5 + c*7, a*9 + c*11, a*13 + c*15},
>
> 2x {e*1 + g*3, e*5 + g*7, e*9 + g*11, e*13 + g*15}

And what's scarier still is if I swap rhsHolders[0/1] in the ternary conditional, it doesn't change the results at all. It's as though the compiler is ignoring one of the swaps and adds. Both Clang 4 and GCC 7 do this, so where did I screw up?

EDIT: output should be 4 rows of {10, 26, 42, 58}, but I get {4, 12, 20, 28}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The SSE code oddly enough is using scalar operations, which boggles my mind since that can definitely be accelerated with horizontal broadcasts, muls, and adds.

Do you mean the compiler-generated assembly code?  All the AVX instructions in `MatMul()` in the clang4.0 and gcc7.1 outputs are operating on ymm vectors.  Except for clang's stupid broadcast-loads: it does a scalar load and then a separate AVX2 broadcast instruction, which is extra bad because Intel CPUs handle broadcast-loads as single-uop ALU instructions.  The load port itself can do the broadcast.  But if the source is a register, it needs an ALU uop for the shuffle port.

```
    vmovss  xmm5, dword ptr [rdi + 24] # xmm5 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    vbroadcastss    xmm5, xmm5
```

clang's actual output (above) is really silly compared to an AVX1 `vbroadcastss  xmm5, [rdi + 24]` like gcc uses.

**In `main()`, clang does emit scalar operations**.

**Since your input matrices are both compile-time constants**, the only mystery is why it didn't optimize down to `cout << "a long string with the numbers already formatted\n";`, or at least optimize away all the math and just have the `double` results ready for printing.  (And yes, they are being converted from `float` to `double` in the print loop with `vcvtss2sd`.)

It optimizes through some of the intrinsic shuffles and math, doing them at compile time.  I guess clang got lost somewhere in the shuffles, and still emitted some math operations.  The fact that they're scalar may be an indication that there wasn't much work it didn't do at compile time, but that it didn't reorder things to vectorize it.

Note that some of the constants do not appear in the source, and they're not in ascending order in memory.

```
...
.LCPI1_5:
        .long   1092616192              # float 10
.LCPI1_6:
        .long   1101004800              # float 20
.LCPI1_7:
        .long   1098907648              # float 16
...
```

It's really nice how clang puts the float value in a comment after the integer representation of the bit pattern.

---

> **or did I actually mess up the algorithm structure somewhere?**

Well, this part of the implementation looks totally bogus.   You initialize `lowerHalf` from `rows[j]`, but then overwrite that value in the next statement.

```
__m128 lowerHalf = _mm256_castps256_ps128(rows[j]);
    lowerHalf = _mm_broadcast_ss(&lhs[offset+2*j]);
```

And then you do a 256b multiply with the upper 128b lane of `rows[j]` undefined.

```
    rows[j] = _mm256_castps128_ps256(lowerHalf);
    rows[j] = _mm256_mul_ps(rows[j], (chooser) ? rhsHolders[0] : rhsHolders[1]);
```

In the asm from gcc and clang, the upper lane is all zero (because they make the obvious choice of using the ymm register last written by the scalar -> xmm broadcast, which implicitly zero-extends to the max vector width).  Note that zero-extending isn't guaranteed by `_mm256_castps128_ps256`.  It's very likely unless the `__m128` was itself the result of an extract/cast from a 256b or wider vector, but it is undefined.  See [How to clear the upper 128 bits of __m256 value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384879/how-to-clear-the-upper-128-bits-of-m256-value) for cases where you need a zeroed upper lane in a vector.

Anyway, this means you'd get the same result from a 128b vector multiply (`vmulps xmm, xmm, xmm`): the upper 4 elements will all be zero (or NaN) after these instructions

```
    vbroadcastss    xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi+40]
    vmulps  ymm0, ymm2, ymm0
```

This kind of asm output (from gcc7.1) is highly unlikely to be part of a correct matmul implementation.

I didn't look carefully to figure out what exactly you were trying to do in the source, but I assume it wasn't exactly this.

---

> And what's scarier still is if I swap rhsHolders[0/1] in the ternary conditional, it doesn't change the results at all. It's as though the compiler is ignoring one of the swaps and adds.

When changing something in the source doesn't produce the change you expect in the asm output, that's a hint that you probably got the source wrong, and something is optimizing away.  Sometimes I copy/paste an intrinsic and forget to change the input variable in the new line, so my function ignores some of its calculation results and uses another one twice.

Answer (score 0):

It will be almost copy&paste from my yesterday answer on SO :)

Try this

```
void MatMul(const float* __restrict lhs , const float* __restrict rhs , float* __restrict out ) 
{
  lhs = reinterpret_cast<float*>(__builtin_assume_aligned (lhs, 32));
  rhs = reinterpret_cast<float*>(__builtin_assume_aligned (rhs, 32));
  out = reinterpret_cast<float*>(__builtin_assume_aligned (out, 32));
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
      for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        out[i*4 + j] += lhs[i*4 + k]*rhs[k*4 + i];
      }
    }     
  }     
}
```

Compile with one of below (measure which one is fastest for you)

```
-O3 -mavx
-O3 -mavx2
-O3 -mavx2 -mfma
-O3 -mavx2 -mfma -ffast-math
```

This works (I mean vectorization) under GCC, cLANG fails to do so for some reason. GCC will unroll the loop too.

Comment: Very cool, but I'd still like to know how I stuffed up my algorithm. Also, the one GCC 7 produces for your code is incredibly wasteful. There's a good 10 cycles an iteration that don't need to be there.

Comment: What iteration?

Comment: It's unrolled, but there's 2 distinct halves, 2 iterations of a larger loop.

Comment: I added a second attempt, cleaned up toward the bottom and shaved 5 cycles.

Comment: You should use `-march=haswell` if that's what you want.  Your options don't override the default `-mtune=generic`, and will split unaligned 256b loads/stores into 128b halves using vinsertf128 / vextractf128.  (You can use `-mavx2 -mfma -ffast-math -mtune=haswell` to tune for haswell without enabling BMI2, popcnt, and other ISA extensions that haswell supports beyond what you used with `-m`.)

Comment: i think it should be rhs[k*4 + j]